# How to get the correspondence between the NVIDIA GPU Minor Number and the GPU UUID?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch, gpu, nvidia

I learned that the X at the end of `/dev/nvidiaX` means NVIDIA GPU Minor Number, and now I want to get the correspondence between the GPU Minor Number and the GPU UUID. Except for `nvidia-smi --query` which will get all the GPU information and then filter it, is there any other better way?

Comment: Define "better".

Comment: @njuffa For example, get the minor number according to uuid directly.

Comment: `nvidia-smi`  is based on the [NVIDIA Management Library (NVML)](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-management-library-nvml), which programmers can also use for their own software.

Comment: Thanks @njuffa, I got it.